# How to pass in the object that takes delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

Fast search for this question gave me nothing. At the same time it's hard to explain, I guess all is clear from this method. Take a look at this, please:

```
func tap(sender: AnyObject, action: Selector) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: sender, action: action)
        tap.delegate = sender
        return tap
    }
```

Error :

```
Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate'
```

The question is what need to write extra for `AnyObject` to avoid of getting this message? Or any other ways?

Comment: What's wrong about writing this piece of code directly instead of making a screenshot?

Comment: Edited. It was faster to understand than now. The answer is simple I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that `sender` always is of type `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` you can use a forced downcast:

```
tap.delegate = sender as UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Otherwise, use a failing cast:

```
if let delegate = sender as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    tap.delegate = delegate
}
```

As reference, have a look at [Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQygQwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FSwift%2FConceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FTypeCasting.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014097-CH22-ID342&ei=ir71VLy4OqLkyAPyz4BQ&usg=AFQjCNEI9TIAirwb6j6n6QRX726lgJ0rSw&sig2=qZCyMvN7Q9fQ2ZsiQ5YB1g) contained in the Swift programming language guide.

Note, that to me this style of assigning the delegate seems to be unusual and error prone.

Comment: Thank, didn't know about such way. That was just to avoid of code duplication. I have a lot views which use this method. Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to say, that there might be an alternative ;)

Comment: another solution :  func tap(sender: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, action: Selector) -> UITapGestureRecognizer {...}

Comment: Yeah, sure. But I meant really another approach of setting the delegate. But it really depends on what you try to achieve, so no need for a discussion.